# Extract data from PDFs at scale with form recognizer: HttpResponseError: (FailedToDownloadImage) Failed to download image from input URL on Databricks

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, azure-cognitive-services

I am trying to extract data from pdfs at scale with Azure Form Recognizer. I am using the [code example at github](https://github.com/tomweinandy/form_recognizer_demo)

I have entered the code as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

field_list = ["InvoiceId", "VendorName", "VendorAddress", "CustomerName", "CustomerAddress", "CustomerAddressRecipient", "InvoiceDate", "InvoiceTotal", "DueDate"]
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=field_list)

for blob in container.list_blobs():
  blob_url = container_url + "/" + blob.name
  poller = form_recognizer_client.begin_recognize_invoices_from_url(invoice_url=blob_url)
  invoices = poller.result()
  print("Scanning " + blob.name + "...")
  
  for idx, invoice in enumerate(invoices):
      single_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=field_list)

      for field in field_list:
        entry = invoice.fields.get(field)
        
        if entry:
          single_df[field] = [entry.value]
          
      single_df['FileName'] = blob.name
      df = df.append(single_df)

df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
df
```

However, I keep on getting the following error:

> HttpResponseError: (FailedToDownloadImage) Failed to download image from input URL.

My URL looks like the following:

```
https://blobpretbiukblbdev.blob.core.windows.net/demo?sp=racwdl&st=2022-05-21T19:39:07Z&se=2022-05-22T03:39:07Z&sv=2020-08-04&sr=c&sig=XYhdecG2jKF8aNPPpkcP%2FCGVVRKYTFPrOQYdNDsASCA%3D/pdf1.pdf
```

NB:
The key has been regenerated, I have just left the key in as it will appear in my code for illustration.

Where might I be going wrong?

Comment: Can I get some thoughts on this question please

Comment: ok, so I changed the code a little to ```form_recognizer_client.begin_recognize_invoices(invoice=blob_url)```
But now I'm getting the error:
```ValueError: Content type could not be auto-detected because the stream was not readable/seekable. Please pass the content_type keyword argument.```
Any thoughts please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [REST API](https://westus2.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/form-recognizer-api-v2-preview/operations/AnalyzeLayoutAsync) supportive documentation, there is a need to specify the **Content-Type**. There is a need to set the public access to source via JSON file. Set the Content-Type to `application/pdf`. To make this work, there is a need to install `filetype` package using [link](https://pypi.org/project/filetype/)

```
pip install filetype
```

Check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/applied-ai-services/form-recognizer/how-to-guides/try-sdk-rest-api?tabs=windows&pivots=programming-language-python) for better implementation of REST API to user Form Recognizer SDK.